# Angular 6 Mat-Dialog does not open from router-outlet

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material

I have a problem while trying to open a mat-dialog in my application. 
The weird thing about it is that the dialog doesn't open from the login component which is load by router-outlet:

```
<div class="main-page">
  <div class="header-eco"  *ngIf="resources.user" >
    <eco-header [FormHeader]="'ECO - ' + formHeader"></eco-header>
  </div>
  <button (click)="openDialogTest()"></button>
  <div class="form-container">
      <router-outlet ></router-outlet>
  </div>


  <div class="footer-c"  *ngIf="resources.user" >
    <eco-footer
      [ShowNavPrev]="CanNavBack()"
      [ShowNavNext]="CanNavNext()"
      [prev]="prevPage"
      [next]="nextPage"
      [showAddButton]="ShowAddButton()"
      [disableSaveButton]="DisableSaveButton()"
      [disableAddButton]="DisableAddButton()"
      [showSaveButton]="ShowSaveButton()"
      (SubmitForm)="SubmitForm($event)"
      (AddNewRow)="AddNewRow($event)"
    ></eco-footer>
  </div>
```

when I'm invoking the same code, it work from the "openDialogTest" and not from my login component. 
to open the dialog I'm using the following code:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private http:CommunicationServieService,  private dialog: MatDialog){}

  ForgotPassword(){
    console.log("open")
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ForgotPasswordDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
  }
```

my appModule:

```
import { ForgotPasswordDialogComponent } from './Dialogs/forgot-password-dialog/forgot-password-dialog.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
...
 ForgotPasswordDialogComponent,
    ChangePasswordDialogComponent],
  entryComponents:[BaseDialogComponent,ForgotPasswordDialogComponent,ChangePasswordDialogComponent]
```

---

Edit

I added some console log to make sure that the function is invoked and it does.

my LoginComponent HTML:

```
    <div>
        <a href="#" (click)="ForgotPassword()" class="txt1">
            Forgot Password?
        </a>
    </div>
```

my Login Component ts:

```
ForgotPassword(){
    console.log("open")
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ForgotPasswordDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
  }
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You are opening the dialog from the ForgotPassword function but that function is never used in your code. Your button calls openDialogTest() but that function is not shown anywhere.

Comment: @G.Tranter I added my Login component, as I said in the Edit, I also added some console.log to make sure that the function is being invoked and it does.

Comment: You're leaving something critical out, but I don't know what. People open dialogs from routed components all the time - it is probably the norm.